# Html.DropDownListFor Add Imagem em determinada posição

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde, galera. Estou querendo add uma imagem na segunda posição do DropDownList, alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer isso? Tentei add uma usando com o append e não funcionou.

Comment: Só texto ou colocar literalmente a imagem dentro da Drop?

Comment: Coloca o Código aí pra gente dar uma ajudada de maneira mais fácil.

Comment: Quero adicionar texto e uma imagem junto.  
Estou inserido o código no Html.DropDownListFor da seguinte forma.
$('#ObjetivoId').append($('<option>', { text: "Novo", value: 0, selected: false }));

Comment: Segue o código, @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ObjetivoId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.Objetivos, "Id", "Descricao"),"Selecionar") consigo add uma imagem com css?